# ActionBar Sherlock - android:parentActivityName

Tags: android, android-actionbar

when I add parentActivityName for an activity that extends from SherlockActivity like this

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_second"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >

            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
   </activity>
```

, the following error occur.

error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'parentActivityName' in package 'android'

Please help how to use parentActivityName in ActionBar Sherlock lib.

Comment: whats your compile sdk version and min-sdk version?

Comment: And make sure your support library is included in your proj

Answer (score 0):

parentActivityName is not supported in ActionBarSherlock.
ActionBarSherlock is based on Ice Cream Sandwich. and parentActivityName was added in Jellybean.

**UPDATE:**
If you want to use attribute `parentActivityName` under Jellybean, you can also declare the parent activity with a  element that specifies a value for "android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY".

Try run without `android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >`

Comment: so, is't not possible to use parentActivityName in ActionBarSherlock? Is there any solution?